# Extended Pascal's Triangle Identity -General identity.

Tags: combinatorial-proofs

Hello I'm having trouble understanding the following notation, specifically, what "i" is indexing
in the summation sign and where does the value of "k" come from? Does the value of "k" come from an arbitrary choice of "k" then the index runs from 0 to that choice ?

$$C(n,r)=\sum_{i=0}^k C(n-k,r-k-i) C(k,i) $$

thanks.

Comment: I think the left hand side may be $C(n,r-k)$ rather than $C(n,r)$

Comment: $i$ simply runs through the integers $0,1,2,\ldots,k-1,k$

Comment: Thanks, I did copy it correctly from the text, obviously the text had a typo. What you said makes it clear,

Comment: If you let $s = r-k$ then you would have $C(n,s)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^k C(n-k,s-i) C(k,i)$ as being true for all sensible $k$